# Access VPN Network From LAN Device

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking, router, vpn

[image: Home Connection Diagram]

I have a Router which is connected to Internet. I have a Laptop  and a Android Device which is connected to this router (Router Does NAT ). My Laptop also have a VPN interface to connect to a different network .
I want to access VPN network from my Android device. Can I access the VPN network from my android Device without setting up a second VPN access. If yes, what is the way ahead ?

Comment: I do this with IPSec VPN and an IPSec client app. Works from anywhere in the world I have been. So that is a decent way forward.

Comment: @John Do we need to add routes to Laptop or Mobile .

Comment: I have not added routers because the VPN router handles the main subnet.